# How to change the background of a specific div when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Note: I don't know jQuery so please don't give me an answer how how to do it using jQuery.

I have multiple divs.  I want to know how I could access it and change its specific color when clicked using JavaScript.

I am not looking for a solution like `document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]` because it requires inputting a seperate number for each div.

I was hoping there was a simple solution somewhat like this.

```
<div onClick="change();"><h1>Hi</h1><div>
<div onClick="change();"><h1>Hi</h1><div>       
<div onClick="change();"><h1>Hi</h1><div>   

<script>
        function change(){
            this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want to learn jQuery (or presumably, non-inline events), consider:

```
<div onclick="change(this)"><h1>Hi Dave!</h1></div>   <!-- use closing tags -->
<div onclick="change(this)"><h1>Hi Thomas!</h1></div>   

function change(elm) {
    elm.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
}
```

Note that the context (`this`) of the inline event handler code (as specified in the attribute) is the element which was the target of the event - for this case it will be the *specific* DIV element that was clicked. We then simply pass the element into the callback function so we can use it generically.

Also, in the initial markup, the div elements *were not closed* and led to nesting. With the corrections, the [above approach works](http://jsfiddle.net/8qj7c/) to complete the task. (The fiddle code assigns to `window.change` directly, but it's otherwise the same concept.)

---

Of course, learning jQuery (or a different) high-level framework will probably pay off quite quickly. Using inline event-handlers is .. very "old school".

Answer (score 0):

This would be more easy.

```
<div onclick="changeColor(this)">Some text!</div>
<p>A paragraph, that will have no change by click</p>
```

For JavaScript write this:

```
function changeColor(div) {
  div.style.backgroundColor = #hexvalue
}
```

This will change the background color of the `div` and not the `<p>`. You can set any css value for any element by using this jQuery code.

However, for me the jQuery was pretty easy! :) But as you wish.